# Crash on clicking on hyperlink in RichTextBlock

Tags: c#, xaml, hyperlink, windows-phone-8.1, richtextblock

I'm building a chat app where I use several `RichTextBlock` for displaying chat messages.

Some of them contain one or more `Hyperlink` objects.

My problem is that when I click on one of these hyperlinks the app crashes with a `Access Violation` exception. This only happens if the input `TextBox`of the chat has focus and the virtual keyboard is displayed on screen. When they keyboard is closed / focus of `TextBox` is cleared, it works without any problems.

I've found a similar issue here: [Hyperlink in RichTextBlock makes the application crash on clicking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35216533/hyperlink-in-richtextblock-makes-the-application-crash-on-clicking)

However, the accepted answer does not help me, because I can't use a `HyperlinkButton` instead of a `Hyperlink`. The hyperlinks can occur in between normal text and should handle line breaks and similar stuff.

Do you have any idea on how to solve this? So far, I've only found out, that this seems to be a common bug, but no solution on how to fix it.

EDIT: After tapping the link the app just closes and the console prints out

`The program '[2296] app.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.`

The global handler for unhandled exceptions is also not called.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Thanks, I've added it to my question. Unfortunately, it is not that much :/

Comment: You have to debug your app or to use some kind of logger to get the exception stack trace.

Comment: I'm debugging it, but it won't break at the exception (all exception types enabled). I will do some further research on logging.

Comment: Can you please show the way you are dealing the rich textbox and hyperlink with `XAML`??

Comment: I use `Underline` instead of `Hyperlink` due to few reasons and process clicks by self. You can try the same, it's easy. Add attached property to `RichTextBlock` like 'ClickAction' and call it from `Click` event of `Hyperlink` block.